# Ubuntu Server 20.04 install custom partitioning

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, raid, btrfs, bcache

Back when using OpenSUSE for my server, I devised a partitioning scheme that I was very satisfied with - a BTRFS RAID10 on bcache devices. I wanted to recreate this with Ubuntu Server 20.04, but so far I failed because subiquity seems to not support bcache or btrfs RAIDs.

`lsblk` output:

```
root@ubuntu-server:/# lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0         7:0    0 351.9M  1 loop /media/filesystem
loop1         7:1    0 223.7M  1 loop 
loop2         7:2    0  57.1M  1 loop /usr/lib/modules
loop3         7:3    0  29.9M  1 loop /snap/snapd/8542
loop4         7:4    0    55M  1 loop /snap/core18/1880
loop5         7:5    0    51M  1 loop /snap/subiquity/1966
sda           8:0    0   2.7T  0 disk 
`-bcache0   252:0    0   2.7T  0 disk /target
sdb           8:16   0   2.7T  0 disk 
`-bcache1   252:128  0   2.7T  0 disk 
sdc           8:32   0   2.7T  0 disk 
`-bcache2   252:256  0   2.7T  0 disk 
sdd           8:48   0   2.7T  0 disk 
`-bcache3   252:384  0   2.7T  0 disk 
sde           8:64   1  57.3G  0 disk 
|-sde1        8:65   1   914M  0 part /cdrom
|-sde2        8:66   1   3.9M  0 part 
`-sde3        8:67   1  56.4G  0 part /var/crash
nvme0n1     259:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
|-nvme0n1p1 259:1    0     1G  0 part 
`-nvme0n1p2 259:2    0 464.8G  0 part 
  |-bcache0 252:0    0   2.7T  0 disk /target
  |-bcache1 252:128  0   2.7T  0 disk 
  |-bcache2 252:256  0   2.7T  0 disk 
  `-bcache3 252:384  0   2.7T  0 disk
```

where the bcache devices make up a btrfs raid using this command:

`# mkfs.btrfs -d raid10 -m raid10 /dev/bcache0 /dev/bcache1 /dev/bcache2 /dev/bcache3`

This entire part has been created using the shell accessible from the installer before getting into the partitioning part of the installer.

In the partitioning part, I chose `Custom storage layout`.

In the partitioner, the caching device (Samsung SSD, partition 2) is shown as unused, as well as all 4 devices used in the BTRFS Raid, as can be seen in the image below.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hE4A.png]

The Toshiba HDD's are `/dev/sdX`'s, not `/dev/bcacheY`'s, so it is absolutely clear that the installer doesn't recognize the partitions that I have already set up.

How can I continue the installation, setting my BTRFS RAID as root?
i.e. `/dev/bcache0` would be mounted on `/` when the installation is finished.

As example, it is mounted on `/target` in `lsblk`, as the shell said that that would be the installation root.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something the installer doesn't offer,  the easiest way would be to make the initial install to another device (some usb stick maybe) and then copy it from there.

- install to additional device
- live boot the system
- make your partitioning scheme
- rsync everything to the final installplace
- update fstab with the correct mount points and uuids
- chroot into the new system
- create new initramfs
- install grub

I did such kind of installs yet to test F2FS as system partition e.g.

L